# How to solve LQR if regulating outputs instead of states?

Tags: optimization, control-theory, optimal-control, linear-control

Consider the state space system given by
$$ \dot{x} = Ax(t) + Bu(t)$$
$$ y = Cx(t) + Du(t)$$

The standard LQR cost is given by
$$ J = \int \big( x(t)^T Q x(t) + u(t)^T R u(t) \big)dt$$

Instead, consider the cost given by
$$ J = \int \big( y(t)^T Q y(t) + u(t)^T R u(t) \big)dt$$

Typically, the states are regulated by designing an observer, but here, the cost is based only on the output not the states. I can't find any references on this scenario, and I am not sure how to solve this problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I will base this [anwer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3154644/369884) on the answer by Johan Löfberg to a related question, where I asked how to include costs on the state derivatives $\dot{x}$. The answer is practically the same if you want the output $y$ instead.

You have the the state space equations

$$
\begin{align}
\dot{x} &= A x + B u \\
y &= C x + D u
\end{align}
$$

The general cost function for the linear quadratic regulator (LQR) is

$$
J_1 = \int_0^\infty (x^T Q x + u^T R u + 2 x^T N u) \, dt
$$

If you want to put a cost directly on the output $y$ you can do that:

$$
\begin{align}
y^T L y &= (C x + D u)^T L (C x + D u) \\
&= x^T (C^T L \,C)x + x^T(C^T L \, D)u + u^T(D^T L \, C)x + u^T(D^T L \, D)u \\
&= x^T (C^T L \,C)x + u^T(D^T L \, D)u + 2 x^T (C^T L \, D) u
\end{align}
$$

So if you want replace a general cost function which has a cost for $y$ with the standard cost function:

$$
\begin{align}
J_2 &= \int_0^\infty (x^T Q x + u^T R u + 2 x^T N u + y^T L y) \, dt \\
&= \int_0^\infty ( x^T \bar{Q} x + u^T \bar{R} u + 2 x^T \bar{N}u  ) \, dt
\end{align}
$$

and the new matrices

$$
\begin{align}
\bar{Q} &= Q + C^T L \, C \\
\bar{R} &= R + D^T L \, D \\
\bar{N} &= N + C^T L \, D
\end{align}
$$

You can then solve the LQR problem with $J_2$ instead of $J_1$ with the standard methods. Of course you must take $Q, R, N, L$  so that $\bar{Q}, \bar{R}, \bar{N}$ satisfy the requirements for LQR.

The nice thing is that if $D = 0$ and you set $N = 0$ that you have the LQR problem without mixed term because then $\bar{N} = 0$. This is good for robustness (see the comments by Kwin van der Veen to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3196981/369884) answer by Arastas).

However, you will still need all states for the controller because it is still of the form $u=-K x$.